# Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance in laravel when merging two arrays

Tags: laravel, collections

In laravel I faced that issue when using array merge in controller . I have to use it because I want to show data from both arrays and show them in one table of laravel so how could I resolve that error and what does it actually means?
my controller

```
 $array1=DB::table('table1')
              ->whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())
              ->select('table1.name as name','table1.age as age')
              ->get();
    $array2=DB::table('table1')
              ->leftJoin('table_2','table1.id','=','table2.table1_id')
              ->whereDate('new_date', Carbon::today())
              ->select('table1.name as name','table2.age as age')
              ->get();
    $data=array_merge(array($array1,$array2));
    
    return view('index')->with('records',$data)
```

my view

```
@foreach($records as $record)
<td>{{$record->name}}</td>
@endforeach
```

error

```
Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add -> toArray()  after ->get().

and in the view use {{$record['name']}}.

and use array merge like this: $data=array_merge($array1,$array2);

Comment: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: try to do dd($data) to see if $data is realy an array

Answer (score 0):

its because arrow is for **objects** and does not work for **array**

you should use $record['name'] and if that array has this index it will show for you

otherwise it does not have that index at all!

Answer (score 0):

you are merging your array result in wrong way ...

you should pass your arrays as parameters not array of parameters

```
$array1=DB::table('table1')
              ->whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())
              ->select('table1.name as name','table1.age as age')
              ->get()->toArray();
    $array2=DB::table('table1')
              ->leftJoin('table_2','table1.id','=','table2.table1_id')
              ->whereDate('new_date', Carbon::today())
              ->select('table1.name as name','table2.age as age')
              ->get()->toArray();
    $data=array_merge($array1,$array2);
```

and make sure you use method `toArray()` to convert you query result to array.

in your blade you should access the variable as an array item not an object:

```
$record['name']
```

see [php array_merge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Comment: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: you can not use array_merge on collections of type stdclass, you should use toArray() method

Answer (score 0):

`get()` returns a collection which is not an array so you should use the [collection merge method](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-merge)

```
$data= $array1->merge($array2);
```